# Remove selected attachment from listbox and from SPlist

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected)
                    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items[i]
                         // this removes from the listbox view but not from the SPList

                        );

            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList myList = web.Lists["MyList"];
            string listUrl = web.Url + "/" + myList.RootFolder.Url;

            string attachmentUrl;
            if (ListBox1.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                string filename = ListBox1.Attachments[0];
                attachmentUrl = listUrl + "/attachments/" + item.ID + "/" + filename;
            }
            ListBox1.Attachments.Delete(filename); 

 // here my Attachments get red... can maybe some help me?



            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in chat, your Attachments keyword gets red, because ReSharper is trying to tell you, that the ListBox class has not Attachments property. I think this question can be considered closed. :)